# Find matching IDs in two big files

Tags: awk, sed

I have 2 big files.

*file1* has 160 million lines with this format:  `id:email`

*file2* has 45 million lines with this format:   `id:hash`

The problem is to find all equal *id*s and save those to a third file, with the format:  `email:hash`

Tried something like:

```
awk -F':' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} {print a[$1]":"$2}' test1.in test2.in > res.in
```

But it's not working :(

Example *file1*:

```
9305718:test00@yahoo.com 
59287478:login@hotmail.com
```

*file2*:

```
21367509:e90100b1b668142ad33e58c17a614696ec04474c
9305718:d63fff1d21e1a04c066824dd2f83f3aeaa0edf6e
```

Desired result:

```
test00@yahoo.com:d63fff1d21e1a04c066824dd2f83f3aeaa0edf6e
```

Comment: 160m records are probably not going to fit in memory.  Are these files sorted by id?  If so, `join` is a better tool for this task.

Comment: Yes, it's sorted. But not all ids are in second file, is not this a problem?

Comment: The Example *file2* data is _not_ sorted.  Should it be?

Answer (score 1):

With GNU join and GNU bash:

```
join -t : -j 1 <(sort -t : -k1,1 file1) <(sort -t : -k1,1 file2) -o 1.2,2.2
```

**Update**:

```
join -t: <(sort file1) <(sort file2) -o 1.2,2.2
```

Comment: nji$ join -t: <(sort test1.in) <(sort test2.in) -o 1.2,2.2
usage: join [-a fileno | -v fileno ] [-e string] [-1 field] [-2 field]
            [-o list] [-t char] file1 file2

Comment: Trying:
join -t:  -o 1.2,2.2 <(sort test1.in) <(sort test2.in)
:d63fff1d21e1a04c066824dd2f83f3aeaa0edf6e
:361e7976e4b783517aca819caf1322c2e0b8cd32

Comment: If both inputs *are* already sorted, (as the OP states), this alone should work:

    `join -t: file1 file2 -o 1.2,2.2 > file3`

Answer (score 0):

In AWK (not considering the amount of resources you have available):

```
$ awk -F':' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} a[$1] {print a[$1]":"$2}' test1.in test2.in
test00@yahoo.com :d63fff1d21e1a04c066824dd2f83f3aeaa0edf6e
```